# Unable to init microstack (snap version openstack) due to nginx complaining. any suggestions?

Tags: nginx, openstack

Hi community out there.

Am trying to install openstack on an ubuntu 20.04 server but init fails by nginx complaining

```
user01@metropolis:/var/opt$ sudo microstack.init --auto
[sudo] Passwort für user01: 
2020-08-27 12:07:41,204 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring networking ...
2020-08-27 12:07:53,190 - microstack_init - INFO - Opening horizon dashboard up to *
2020-08-27 12:07:56,342 - microstack_init - INFO - Waiting for RabbitMQ to start ...
Waiting for 10.20.20.1:5672
2020-08-27 12:08:46,544 - microstack_init - INFO - RabbitMQ started!
2020-08-27 12:08:46,544 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring RabbitMQ ...
2020-08-27 12:08:50,572 - microstack_init - INFO - RabbitMQ Configured!
2020-08-27 12:08:50,629 - microstack_init - INFO - Waiting for MySQL server to start ...
Waiting for 10.20.20.1:3306
2020-08-27 12:08:50,643 - microstack_init - INFO - Mysql server started! Creating databases ...
/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1007, "Can't create database 'neutron'; database exists")
  result = self._query(query)
/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1287, "Using GRANT statement to modify existing user's properties other than privileges is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Use ALTER USER statement for this operation.")
  result = self._query(query)
/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1007, "Can't create database 'nova'; database exists")
  result = self._query(query)
/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1007, "Can't create database 'nova_api'; database exists")
  result = self._query(query)
/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1007, "Can't create database 'nova_cell0'; database exists")
  result = self._query(query)
/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1007, "Can't create database 'cinder'; database exists")
  result = self._query(query)
/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1007, "Can't create database 'glance'; database exists")
  result = self._query(query)
/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1007, "Can't create database 'keystone'; database exists")
  result = self._query(query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/microstack/206/bin/microstack_init", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('microstack-init==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'microstack_init')())
  File "/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/init/main.py", line 54, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/init/main.py", line 138, in init
    question.ask()
  File "/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/init/questions/question.py", line 210, in ask
    self.yes(awr)
  File "/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/init/questions/__init__.py", line 358, in yes
    check('snapctl', 'start', 'microstack.nginx')
  File "/snap/microstack/206/lib/python3.6/site-packages/init/shell.py", line 68, in check
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, " ".join(args))
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'snapctl start microstack.nginx' returned non-zero exit status 1.
user01@metropolis:/var/opt$ netstat | grep :80 
tcp        0      0 metropolis:55384        192.168.178.75:8009     VERBUNDEN  
tcp        0      0 metropolis:48726        192.168.178.129:8009    VERBUNDEN  
tcp        0      0 metropolis:59164        192.168.178.101:8009    VERBUNDEN  
tcp        0      0 metropolis:50820        172.30.33.5:8086        VERBUNDEN  
user01@metropolis:/var/opt$ netstat | grep :443
tcp        0      0 metropolis:44324        192.168.178.12:http     TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 metropolis:44376        192.168.178.12:http     TIME_WAIT  
user01@metropolis:/var/opt$
```

Can someone please explain, why nginx complains or where to review logs? Am new to snap.
Any other suggestions also welcome? No Apache or Nginx running

Comment: I did come across this bug in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/microstack/+bug/1859002 They suggest: stop the Apache server.

You can do that by executing: sudo service apache2 stop

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But as (maybe too short handed) said I do not have any Apache nor Nginnx up and running. Thats my issue. I would gladly stop any service consuming the ports needed by nginx but I don't have any of these services nor ports open....

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem but with microstack.ovs.vswitchd

To solve the problem I had to install openvswitch-switch-dpdk.

Your solution may be to install nginx or reinstall it..

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, I tried to check if apache2 was running on the same port but in my ubuntu-ec2 instance, I haven't installed apache2 so technically I shouldn't have this error.

So, I look for if any other service was running using the [network tools](https://websiteforstudents.com/find-all-open-ports-listening-ports-on-ubuntu-18-04-16-04/)

Then I found out that the datadog-agent service was using the same port, I removed the service and then tried to initialize microstack using microstack init --auto --control and it worked. After the microstack was up and running, I then installed a datadog-agent to monitor my ec2 instance.

If you still have this error, look for ports using the network tools and try to remove those services and re-install after you initialize the microstack.

My Ec2 Details:

Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS

RAM: 8GB

Storage: 20Gb

VCPU: 2

t2.large